# Add column to pandas df which is equal to another column, but different row

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to add a column to a df which is equal to another column, but the row above. I have a column representing the percentage change in a given day, and I want to add another column which has the percentage change of the two previous days also.

This is the code I used to get the "% change" column

```
tickerDf['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(tickerDf['Date'])
Close = tickerDf['Close'].shift()
tickerDf['% change'] = np.where(
    tickerDf['Date'].dt.day.diff().gt(0), ((tickerDf['Open'] - Close) / Close) * 100, '')
```

[This image indicates what I am trying to achieve.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8OHIK.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create the new column after setting up `tickerDf['% change']` by using `.shift()`, as follows:

```
tickerDf['% change-1'] = tickerDf['% change'].shift(1)
```